# portal powered gun

Tags: science-fiction, weapons

Is a portal powered gun feasible? By portal powered I mean a projectile in dropped into one portal then goes through the portal into the other portal and is basically in freefall until the portal is connected to a portal on the front of the gun firing the projectile going crazy speeds at something. Is this idea feasible assuming we have working portal technology and almost limitless power sources.

please ask for more information if needed.

Comment: If you have working portal technology with such precision, why not just pull a Wile-E-Coyote and drop an enormous boulder through a single portal onto your target's head? Or open a portal *inside their body* to do all kinds of heinous damage? Or drop your target through a portal below their feet into a prison...or a grinder?

Comment: What do you mean by *"feasible"* ?  It's certainly not technologically possible as far as we know, so in what way do you mean feasible ?  There are severe issues with conservation of energy and momentum, BTW - you're adding momentum and energy and it's got to come from somewhere and be balanced somehow.  Nature tends to keep very strict accounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, but there's not really a point to it**

Assuming we had working portal technology and almost limitless power sources, it's feasible. Some minor calibration issues would exist, notably because the constant acceleration due to gravity would be problematic, problematic in this context meaning 'starting to turn the air to plasma'. The air resistance in between the portal wouldn't really slow it down that much assuming that the portals operate in a close system because that air would be gradually accelerated as well. And if you're using a system open to Earth's atmosphere - well, that seems like of silly and risky given that a gust of wind could blow your projectile off track because the slightest acceleration to one side would mean that the projectile would eventually tumble out of the portal. Not to mention that with normal air resistance, it's not going to be going 'crazy fast', and in fact will be going slower than some guns can fire bullets. Given all that, you would also needs the means to drop said projectile with ludicrous precision in the first place, and honestly, it still wouldn't be as precise as a bullet, because bullets spin. This projectile wouldn't spin, so not much accuracy.

Given all the constraints and risks, conventional guns are just better. And, given that apparently you can just fire a portal to the moon, it's not even useful for building up speeds to launch rockets when you don't even need rockets in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother when we can just portal our enemies to who knows where? I mean, just make two portals that drop into each other. He'd be there forever.